# RSpec testing for non-integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I recently created an account model.  In this account model i have an id which i want to be strictly numeric.  I am trying to create an RSpec test to make sure that I can not enter in any letters, but am having difficulty.

Question: how do I test my id to make sure that it can not contain any letters?

Answer (score 0):

Use `kind_of` like so:

```
object.should be_a_kind_of(Numeric)
```

From the [documentation](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html):

```
3.should be_a_kind_of(Fixnum) => 3.kind_of?(Numeric) #passes
3.should be_a_kind_of(Numeric) => 3.kind_of?(Numeric) #passes
3.should be_an_instance_of(Fixnum) => 3.instance_of?(Fixnum) #passes
3.should_not be_instance_of(Numeric) => 3.instance_of?(Numeric) #fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can kill two bird with one stone with a expectation like this

```
subject.should be_eql 3
```

since it will have right type and right value. Using `eql?` guarantees you that `id1.hash == id2.hash`

Although, you can always split your case into two expectations: value and type. For type matching you can use `kind_of` matcher or check inheritance with `<` operator on classes.

```
subject.should be_kind_of(Numeric)
```

or

```
subject.class.should < Numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, in Rails you cannot save any other data type in the primary_key attribute.